# Open multiple links, in random order, by clicking one link

Tags: javascript, random, hyperlink, tabs

(This is for a client who needs the function for a focus group test)

I am trying to create a link that when clicked will open three tabs to three different urls - each time in random order.

So "Click me" would open example.com, google.com, facebook in three tabs at once, in random order. So first click it might be example.com, google.com, facebook.com - next click might be google.com, facebook.com, example, and so on.

So far I have this code, it selects a random link, but only one of them - I want to open all three at once, but in random order

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var urls = [
        "http://example.com",
        'http://google.com',
        'http://facebook.com'
    ];

    function goSomewhere() {
        var url = urls[Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length)];
        window.location = url; // redirect
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onClick="goSomewhere(); return false;">Start</a>
```

Comment: @shyammakwana.me No, this is for a customer who needs it for a function in a focus group test. So will not be used for anything sinister :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function goSomewhere() {
 while(urls.length)
    window.open(...urls.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length),1),"Test");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But your solution still only opens one of the links, and not all three at once.